# Is it ok to cast an unknown Object to a specifc Interface?

Tags: java, casting

UPDATE: Let me add a complication here.  Suppose that `createObject()` returns an `Object` that actually implements 2 interfaces - `SomeInterface` and `AnotherInterface`.  The caller, in order to use the `Object` has to type-cast it to one of the interfaces.  In this case, would the code-snippet below be ok?

---

I have a "factory-method" which internally creates an object of some "unknown" type and returns just an "Object".  The documentation of that factory-method (say createObject() ) clearly says that the object thus created / returned would implement a specific interface (say SomeInterface).  So I have a code-snippet as follows:

```
SomeInterface intf = (SomeInterface) createObject();
```

I am ok if this causes a runtime exception if (say) `createObject()` returns an `Object` that doesn't implement `SomeInterface`.  But a Java maven says this code is "wrong" - the reason (according to him) is, `createObject()` must return `SomeInterface`.

I am not quite convinced and am willing learn from the community here.

Comment: ............ it depends

Comment: that depends on the circumstances and the contracts in your code

Comment: The reason the compiler is warning you is because this is generally an unsafe thing to do and there is almost always a better way to do this. There is almost no reason to ever return `Object`. Hard to advise further without seeing your code. Please edit your question and provide the code in it.

Comment: @DanPantry Hibernate calls to retrieve a result set being one notable exception :-)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen could you link docs for that? I've not used hibernate in quite some time and could do with brushing up :)

Comment: @DanPantry [Poke around here](https://www.journaldev.com/3422/hibernate-native-sql-query-example) which discusses raw/native queries with Hibernate.  A result set is modeled as `List<Object[]>`

Comment: We need to see the actual definition of the `createObject` method. What happens if you remove the cast?

Comment: I know this doesn't help you, but if the documentation says the returned object implements a certain interface, the method should use this as return type.

Comment: Thanks to all who responded.  I have added an update to my query.  Kindly look into it and please let me know accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Maven is saying correctly - that factory method is not great. But assuming the problem is caused by the external (unchangeable by you) code, you have only 3 ways out:

- add a boilerplate code to calm down maven
- add some suppress warnings annotation/marker for this code fragment only (if possible)
- reconfigure maven to ignore that (not recommended!)
- or just live with that...

Pros and cons of every solution are quite clear - and you must make the choice :)

Comment: to clarify, by "maven" I didn't mean Apache Maven :-)

Comment: It doesn't change anything, also your update doesn't. Answer is still the same - you decide what suits you best

Answer (score 0):

As this would not be a compiler error, I assume that mave runs a **code style checker**.
Correct the "error" by checking that the created object is an instance of the interface, before the cast.

```
SomeInterface intf = null;
{
    Object obj = createObject();
    if (obj instanceof SomeInterface) {
        intf = (SomeInterface) createObject();
    }
}
```

As the object could be null, and null is never any SomeInterface I give a bit circumstantial code. Adapt as it suites you best.